# Active navbar won't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, navbar, fullpage.js

I'm building a website with section, and i want them to scroll on each section. For this i'm using fullpage.js and all working good. I also have a menu and i want when we are in the first section, the first tab is active. Here is the problem, if i put data-spy="scroll" on my body tag[image], it's only the last tab which is active. I'm using bootstrap for the css.

here is my html page without all unsued class and div

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar">
    <div class="nav_div col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                <li class="active"><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link">link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>    
    </div>
    <span id="fullpage" class="col-sm-12">
        <section id="link" class="section active">
            bla bla bla
        </section>
        <section id="link" class="section">
            bla bla bla
        </section>
        <section id="link" class="section">
            bla bla bla
        </section>
        <section id="link" class="section">
            bla bla bla
        </section>
        <section id="link" class="section">
            bla bla bla
        </section>
    </span>
</body>
```

here is my js for have the active tab on scrolling, which is work if i desactivate fullpage.js

```
$(function() {
         "use strict";
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 700);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

and the fullepage js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage({
            responsiveWidth: 768,
            scrollOverflow: true
        });
    });
```

Comment: You need to setup a minimal, working example that demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve. [mcve]

Comment: Ok, sure, i have added, if you need other things for try fixing my issue, just tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is right in the [Documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#options), go to **Options** then **MENU**.

> menu: (default false) A selector can be used to specify the menu to
>   link with the sections. This way the scrolling of the sections will
>   activate the corresponding element in the menu using the class active.
>   This won't generate a menu but will just add the active class to the
>   element in the given menu with the corresponding anchor links. In
>   order to link the elements of the menu with the sections, an HTML 5
>   data-tag (data-menuanchor) will be needed to use with the same anchor
>   links as used within the sections. Example:

Navigation Example

```
<ul id="myMenu">
    <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#firstPage">First section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#thirdPage">Third section</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="fourthPage"><a href="#fourthPage">Fourth section</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS Example

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage', 'lastPage'],
    menu: '#myMenu'
});
```

You have to add an HTML 5 data-tag (`data-menuanchor`) to all of your anchor links and use the same name for your HREFs.

```
data-menuanchor="firstPage" and href="#firstPage"
```

Then add them to your function along with your `UL` ID/Class.

```
anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage'],
menu: '#myMenu'
```

See working example in Snippet at Full Page.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
    fixedElements: '.navbar-fixed-top',
    menu: '#bs-nav',
    anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage'],
    css3: true
  });
  //So the Mobile Nav Hides When a Link is Clicked
  $(".navbar-nav li a").click(function(event) {
    $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.4/jquery.fullPage.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.7.4/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul id="#nav" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="active"><a href="#firstPage">First Page</a>

        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Second Page</a>

        </li>
        <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#thirdPage">Third Page</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div id="fullpage">
  <div id="one" class="section">
    <p>1 Not only vertical scrolling but also horizontal scrolling. With fullPage.js you will be able to add horizontal sliders in the most simple way ever.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="section">
    <p>2 Not only vertical scrolling but also horizontal scrolling. With fullPage.js you will be able to add horizontal sliders in the most simple way ever.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="section">
    <p>3 Not only vertical scrolling but also horizontal scrolling. With fullPage.js you will be able to add horizontal sliders in the most simple way ever.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's worked, the only thing it's when we land on page the last tab is active, we need scroll for have the real one active. I put active class on the first tab but seem not work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, in my example the first navigation link is active by default before you you scroll then changed on either a click/scroll event.

Comment: yes sure, so i will re-check my code for see what is wrong, thanks for you'r help